# Error while testing R package 'slackr'

Tags: r, slack-api, slack

I have set ~/.slackr based on the given manual and run the following code.

```
library(slackr)
slackr_setup()
slackr("iris info", head(iris), str(iris))
```

Then I got the following error message.

> Error: x and y don't share the same src. Set copy = TRUE to copy y into x's source (this may be time consuming).`

Please let me know if you have any idea on this. It would be great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've solved it by myself.

The reason was that I wasn't fill out 'api_token' field in ~/.slackr.
'api_token' field is a mandatory.
So you should get the token from slack.

I've tried with 'test token'. You can get your own from the following url.
https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth-test-tokens